# Turning on HDTV/Monitor on boot or unsuspend

Tags: suspend, power-management, hdtv

I use a 4K HDTV as my monitor, which I highly recommend.  The one issue is that unlike most monitors, it does not power on when it detects a signal appearing on the HDMI.   So if I forget to power on the monitor before resuming/booting, X gets upset and goes into 640x480 mode after I turn it on manually.  I hope to make it work like a typical monitor and power on when I boot.    The TV supports CEC (Samsung calls it Anynet and I have just enabled that) but cec-client finds no devices when I have it query.

I presume I also should insert the desired resolution data into an X.org configuration so that it doesn't do the wrong resolution, but that still would not have it turn on when I resume from sleep, which I would like.    What's the best path to fixing that.

Comment: The TV not waking is a feature of the TV nothing can be done from Ubuntu.

Comment: Not true.  The CEC protocol allows devices connected to a TV over HDMI to send lots of commands both ways, including telling the TV to power on.   It's how your cable box can turn the TV on when you turn it on.

Answer (score 0):

Samsung's implementation of CEC, called Anynet, is proprietary (think MotionRate 120 is still 60hz or QLED is not OLED). It works with other Samsung products such as a TV & Soundbar or Surround Sound Receiver. Does NOT work so great with other manufacturer products. Spent several hours with horrible Samsung customer service until a level 2 engineer disclosed Anynet is for Samsung products only and not a full implementation of CEC standard.

Comment: Really, even with the most simple command I'm looking for, namely "turn the tv on?"